# ç appearing as ‡ in JSON return

Tags: json, unicode, django-rest-framework

When trying to return "Français" from the database, the JSON response changes the ç to ‡.  I have confirmed in the console that the character is saved as ç.

Using SHOW SERVER_ENCODING I have confirmed that the database is UTF8.

When I print the object to the python console before returning, it prints as

```
{'language': u'Fran\u2021ais'}
```

where \u2021 is ‡.

In my settings.py, I have the renderer set:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication'
    ),
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    ),
}
```

I have checked the response in Postman as well as the browser console and on-screen - they all swap the c for the double dagger.

What is causing this?  Is there a work-around?

Comment: One or both of the character sets the database is using is broken; both are character 87 in *very* different character sets. [1](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2021/codepage_support.htm) [2](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00e7/codepage_support.htm)

Comment: I have confirmed that the database is UTF8

Comment: Well, *something* isn't.

Comment: I think that's clear - could you give me some insights into debugging where the charset is changing?

Comment: If everything in the console is UTF-8 then the problem has to be with querying the data.

Comment: How do I ensure psycopg2 receives query results in UTF-8 format?